# How do I log in to Datomic's H2 storage?

Tags: datomic

I'd like to take a look at the data in the H2 database that Datomic Free is using for its storage. When you start the transactor with the default "sample" settings, the data files go into a `data` directory where you expanded datomic. If you're using the default port of 4334 for Datomic, the H2 web console starts at 4336. (The H2 TCP server is at 4335 for the curious.) Knowing all of that, I can go to the web console at `http://localhost:4336` and enter a JDBC URL of `jdbc:h2:<path-to-datomic>/data/db/datomic`, and when I try to connect, I get a "Wrong user name or password" error. So what's the right user name and password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) On my third guess, I found the user and password are both `datomic`.

2) The data in the database isn't very readable. It's mostly a bunch of stuff like this:

```
ID      REV     MAP     VAL  
...
51dae90e-b27c-4ace-821d-d835523e41f9    null    {}  1f8b08000000000000007bfafe614e7eba6e4a661113c3e19b0281b75ef2b547bafd9a1a9459707cd5abe6f340c0c0c0203f8151d817009a6152532b000000
51dae90e-8759-46fa-9552-6970c7aaea83    null    {}  1f8b08000000000000007b721e0818181818654558940081fccfaa0d000000
51dae90e-b712-46da-b810-b245ffb498da    null    {}  ee
51dae90e-335b-4bdb-b721-f02418c19464    null    {:prev "51dae90e-b712-46da-b810-b245ffb498da"}  fec0eacaf7cddc6964c3d91051dae90ee7eb419296bf7c04ba987256caf7cdde64617461eaefdf646174756d06f50353e832c87b3fbf1e610153e8a0f5003e281753e8a0f5003e3de317416e2061746f6d20656e7472792773206964456e74727953e8a0f5003e292353e8a0f5003e0acacde30961746f6d456e7472798053e8a0f500000d3e53e8caf7cddb7453e8
51dae90e-50d5-4fde-ad27-794fc79b0e36    null    {:prev "51dae90e-335b-4bdb-b721-f02418c19464"}  fec0eacaf7cddc6964c3d91051dae90efcd7401687f878e196ae4482caf7cdde64617461eaefdf646174756d06f50353e932c87b3fbf1e61d753e9a0f5003f281753e9a0f5003f3de317416e2061746f6d20656e747279277320636f6e74656e7453e9a0f5003f292353e9a0f5003f0acacde30961746f6d456e747279cde1636f6e74656e7453e9a0f500000d3f53e9caf7cddb7453e9
51dae90e-1c2f-4215-b2f7-86de50700d1d    null    {:prev "51dae90e-50d5-4fde-ad27-794fc79b0e36"}  fec0eacaf7cddc6964c3d91051dae90ea765434587897fdb2d752eb7caf7cdde64617461eaefdf646174756d06f50353ea32c87b3fbf1e61ec53eaa0f5005040281953eaa0f50050403de320416e2061746f6d20656e747279277320277075626c697368656420646174652753eaa0f5005040292353eaa0f50050400acacde30961746f6d456e747279cde17075624461746553eaa0f500000d504053eacaf7cddb7453ea
...
```

I'd guess the VAL is something like hex-encoded [Fressian](https://github.com/Datomic/fressian) data, but I'm too lazy to try decoding it right now.

Comment: I doesn't look like Fressian, I try to decode it and I blocked. Could it be deflate of Fressian ? or something with the licence key ?

Comment: It's just fressian but some entries are also gzipped. You can tell because there's a gzip header and checksum on those binary values that are gzipped.